# Cannot get Nuxt.js, Express, and 3rd-party API to work together

Tags: rest, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have been trying for weeks to get Nuxt.js + Express (using `create-nuxt-app`) to work with a 3rd-party API. No matter what I try, nothing, absolutely nothing, works. No console statement from my server-side gets triggered, only the front-end statements. Also, I recently started getting `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` and I'm not setting headers anywhere in my code.

All I want to do is take user input, pass it through to my back-end to avoid CORS issues, get data back from the 3rd-party API, and then display it. It's simple. It happens all the time on the internet, so why can't I get it to work?

Below are all the files involved in the process described above.

pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="@/assets/images/OscarPark.jpg" alt="Oscar in the park" title="I love the park!" />
    <br />
    <form>
      <label for="title">Book Title:</label>
      <input v-model="titleFromUser" type="text" name="title" class="title" />
      <button @click.prevent="submit" class="submit">Find a Book!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      titleFromUser: '',
    };
  },
  computed: mapState(['newTitles']),
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_BOOK_TITLES', this.titleFromUser);
      this.titleFromUser = '';
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  img {
    transform: rotate(90deg); // this fixes a glitch that causes image to rotate needlessly
    padding-top: $underHeaderGap; // these 2 padding lines help to fix the placement of the image caused by the needless rotation
    padding-left: $underHeaderGap * 5;
    margin-bottom: $underHeaderGap * 5;
    height: $imgHeight;
  }
}
</style>
```

store/index.js:

```
import consola from 'consola';

export const state = () => ({
  newTitles: [],
});

export const mutations = {
  SET_NEW_TITLES(state, newTitles) {
    state.newTitles = newTitles;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  async FETCH_BOOK_TITLES({ commit }, titleFromUser) {
    try {
      consola.ready({
        message: `'FETCH_BOOK_TITLES': titleFromUser: ${titleFromUser}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      const { data } = await this.$axios.$post('/title', { titleFromUser });
      consola.ready({
        message: `data returned from api: ${data}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      commit('SET_NEW_TITLES', data);
    } catch (error) {
      consola.error({
        message: `FETCH_BOOK_TITLES: Something went wrong: ${error}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  },
};
```

server/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const consola = require('consola');
const axios = require('axios');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.json();

const titleRouter = require('../api/title/index');

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

  // Give app ability to parse json
  app.use(jsonParser);

  // Give app ability to get past CORS issues
  app.use(cors());

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready();
  }

  app.use('/title', titleRouter);

  app.get('/title', (req, res) => {
    consola.ready({
      message: `res.json in title endpoint-server: ${res.json()}`,
      badge: true,
    });

    consola.ready({
      message: `req.json in title endpoint-server: ${req.json()}`,
      badge: true,
    });

    const recommendationsURL = `https://tastedive.com/api/similar?q=and+then+there+were+none&type=books&info=1&k=${process.env.TASTE_DIVE_API_KEY}`;

    axios
      .get(recommendationsURL, (req, res) => {
        consola.ready({
          message: `from server/index.js: ${res.json()}`,
          badge: true,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        consola.error({
          message: `error from axios server ${error} `,
          badge: true,
        });
      });
  });

  // Listen to the server
  app.listen(port, host, () => {
    consola.ready({
      message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
      badge: true,
    });
  });
}

start();
```

api/title/index.js:

```
const consola = require('consola');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const titleRouter = express.Router();

titleRouter.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response);
  req.res = res;
  res.req = req;
  next();
});

titleRouter.get('/title', (req, res) => {
  res
    .json()
    .then((data) => {
      consola.ready({
        message: `~api/title get title is ${data}`,
        badge: true,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      consola.error({
        message: `~api/title get Something went wrong: ${error}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      throw new Error(error);
    });
});

titleRouter.post('/title', (req, res) => {
  res
    .json()
    .then((data) => {
      consola.ready({
        message: `~api/title post title is ${data}`,
        badge: true,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      consola.error({
        message: `~api/title post Something went wrong: ${error}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      throw new Error(error);
    });
});

module.exports = titleRouter;
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    title: "Oscar's Book Recommendations",
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || '',
      },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
  ],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {
    https: true,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    watch: ['api/title'],
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {},
  },
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'fade',
    mode: 'out-in',
  },
  env: {
    TASTE_DIVE_API_KEY: process.env.TASTE_DIVE_API_KEY,
  },
  serverMiddleware: ['~api/title'],
  styleResources: {
    scss: ['~assets/styles/main.scss'],
  },
};
```

Does anybody see what I'm not? Why isn't the data going through to the server? Why is it telling me that I can't set headers after they're being sent when I'm not setting them anywhere in my code? What is wrong with this?

I would greatly appreciate anybody's input and help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think I had a similar issue a while back. My problem was, that Nuxt Router always tried to handle the API requests (and find corresponding components in "pages" folder).
It seems to me like you're mixing to concepts here, on one hand you have `server/index.js` and on the other hand you also register `serverMiddleware`. I used the first approach for my project.

Comment: This is basically what I found out what I was doing wrong. Sebastien Chopin came across my tweet about this and, as one of the creators of Nuxt, kindly pointed out something that helped. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it happens that I had a `server/index.js` and a `nuxt.config.js` with a `serverMiddleware` entry. Sebastien Chopin, one of the creators of Nuxt, came across my tweet about this issue and kindly pointed out that I can use either the `server/index.js` file OR the `serverMiddleware` in my `nuxt.config.js`, but NOT both as I had been doing. As somebody who first learned Express by creating server files, I can easily see how this would lead somebody into confusion.

In the end, I settled for using the Nuxt way of doing it and used the `serverMiddleware` in my `nuxt.config.js`. When you set up a Nuxt project and choose to have Express integrated from the start, this is the preferred way of using Express, as opposed to the traditional server files.

Comment: Ive been circling with this issue for a last few hours - was the a paricular setup you needed for your express application?? and did/do you make your requests using axios or http or ....?

Comment: @Jujubes, sorry for the late reply, I only just saw your comment today. I use axios the majority of the time, and I did not have any particular setup for my express, just the "best practices" standard.